# sharepoint search service application throws 404 NOT FOUND

Tags: sharepoint-server, enterprise-search

I have created sharepoint search service application via UI and powershell, and either way it is throwing the same error when I click on the search service application in Central Admin.

```
404 not found.
```

What could possibly be?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Search Host Controller Service and SharePoint Server Search is started via CA->Manage services on server.

And try to activate a hidden feature using command below:

```
Enable-SPFeature SearchAdminWebParts -url <central admin URL>
```

If the feature is already enabled, you need to disable the feature first and then enable it.

```
Disable-SPFeature SearchAdminWebParts -url <central admin URL>
Enable-SPFeature SearchAdminWebParts -url <central admin URL>
```

Run IISReset and check again.

Comment: This feature "searchAdminWebParts" does not exist.